# Images and Directories not showing in Drawables directory

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image

I imported a number of image assets, and I copied the assets into the project by copy/paste them into the project via Finder on my Mac. I've done a clean/rebuild on the project, and the files & directories showed for a moment, but then they disappeared. Now I can't get the files and the directories to show up. The files are clearly in the directory and project, but they don't show in Android Studio. They are labeled `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, and so on. Here is an image of the files:

[image]

Here is my Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Switch to Project view and check.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Switch in project view will show you all folders for example drawable.hdpi and so on check all these folder for all images.

Comment: They are in the project view but I can't reference them in my project

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I added my images to the drawables directory rather than the resources directory! Ugh...